# How to play games on an ubuntu server but redirect all rendering to the client

Tags: games, steam, vnc, opengl, virtualgl

I have an ubuntu server with no graphics card but with very high upload speed. I want to use it to play a game on it which has an integrated mulitplayer server, so whoever hosts the game has to run it (no dedicated game server). My internet speed is very low and I can't host the server but i can run the game. Is there any way to do this? I've been trying with x2go, turbovnc and virtualgl but I can't find a way to do it. My pc is running windows 10. 
I've had some success with x2go , I've managed to run steam on the remote machine, but I was not able to run the game because it required opengl , so i need to somehow redirect opengl calls to my windows client and render them there. 
I've also tried x11 forwarding, but that was just too slow and I couldn't even do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that what you are asking for is possible.  I have been researching various VNC and X11 remote gaming implementation for Ubuntu (18.04 if you are curious) and all implementations of X11 and VNC render ON THE HOST MACHINE, and then transmit the rendered data to the client machine.  Of the two technologies, VNC has been a better option so far.

as a side note, if you think about the transmission capabilities of PCIE versus monitor cables (even HDMI) then it becomes pretty obvious that transmitting the rendered image is far "cheaper" than transmitting the memory required to generate that image.